# Unable to get FirebaseInitProvider exception

Tags: android, firebase

```
          apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

          android {
      compileSdkVersion 25
      buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
      defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.emperors.raaste"
      minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled=true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexEnabled=true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar'
        exclude 'libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

}
}

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-        core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/map_sdk_2.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This id my gradle file, I cannot resolve this issue I just updated Google services and repository and after that I am getting this error unable to get FirebaseInitProvider

I tried `multidexenable=true` and set `MultiDexInstall(this);` inside MultidexApplication still I am getting same exception is there anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have tried to enable Multidex, it does not appear to be correctly configured.  Most likely there is something wrong with the way you have configured your `Application` class.  If you do not need to subclass `Application` for reasons other than Multidex, just use the provided `MultiDexApplication` and modify the `application` element of your manifest with this line:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Otherwise extend your Application class from `MultiDexApplication` as described in the [Multidex configuration instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).

When Multidex is correctly configured and working, you will see messages in your `logcat` like these:

```
I/MultiDex: install
I/MultiDex: MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.qbix.multidextest-10.apk, false)
I/MultiDex: Detected that extraction must be performed.
I/MultiDex: install done
```

Although the current configuration of your app contains more than 65K method references and thus requires Multidex for pre-Lollipop devices, you might be able to eliminate that.  Your dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1` is pulling in ALL the Play Services APIs.  They are [listed here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable*.  Remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1` and replace it with the specific APIs you need.  This will improve your build time, make your APK smaller, and may eliminate the need for Multidex.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the 'Multidex 64K Methods' - problem. The app works fine for Android API level >= 21, but if your minSdkVersion is < 21, you should follow these instructions:

- add "multiDexEnabled true" in "android defaultConfig"
- add "compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'" in "dependencies"
- add 'android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"' in application tag in manifest or change "extends Application" with "extends MultiDexApplication" if you override Application class.

Here's the link to the official page:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html